# Paste formula with cell references in WORD

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm using a formula in WORD with cell references - basically, I'd like to keep a running number down column A, with each row adding 1. A1 = 1, so A2 = A1+1, A3 = A2 + 1, etc. Can I copy down the cell reference like you can in Excel? I don't want to keep typing in the formula manually.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you want Excel-type functionality in your table, consider using Insert>Table>Excel Spreadsheet which is like a mini-Excel right there inside of Word.

Answer (score 0):

Word doesn't have the same facility to "copy down" that Excel does.

But if you have one or more fields in A1, e.g. `{ SEQ A }`, you can copy them (e.g. ctrl-C), then select the cells where you want copies - or select the entire column if that makes sense in your situation, and paste the fields. Word will make a copy in each cell.